# Get href value with onServerClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, href

I'm working with asp.net and c#

I got a list of link and i want to get the href value in the code behind.

So far I have:

```
<li><a href="#?id='101'" runat="server" onServerClick="room_click">Room 101</a></li>
<li><a href="#?id='102'" runat="server" onServerClick="room_click">Room 102</a></li>
<li><a href="#?id='103'" runat="server" onServerClick="room_click">Room 103</a></li>

protected void room_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

The problem is I can't find a solution to get the href value, I tried the anchor or regex but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you trying to get links to be redirected to another page in Code Behind?  If that's what you're trying to do, you can use Page.Response.Redirect(), Page.Response.RedirectPermanent(), or Server.Transfer.  You will need to add the URLs inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to cast the sender to an HtmlAnchor so you can access the property:

```
    public void room_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var href = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor)sender).HRef;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void room_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var anchor = sender as HtmlAnchor;
    if (anchor == null)
        return;

    var href = anchor.HRef;
    //--do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `onServerClick` is going to override your `href` anyway and instead cause a postback... so I'd recommend just removing it all and simply have:

```
<li><a href="?id=101">Room 101</a></li>
<li><a href="?id=102">Room 102</a></li>
<li><a href="?id=103">Room 103</a></li>
```

And then in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RoomClick();
}

private void RoomClick()
{
    int roomId = 0;
    //check to see if the id in the querystring exists and that it parses as an int.
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) && Int32.TryParse((Request.QueryString["id"]), out roomId))
    {
        //do something with roomId
    }
}
```

This way seems more straightforward / easier to use, in my opinion. Jason's answer *will work* for you as well. I think that route is confusing though because although you can read the `href` and get that value, you can't read a `#` value from a URL... and this just isn't a standard way of accomplishing what you want to accomplish. Plus, how were you planning on easily getting the Room # out of that `href`?

The other reason I like this route is you can link someone directly to a room without telling them to click something first... if the `id` is there, it will load the room info or whatever you are doing.

**UPDATE:** If you don't want the room info in the URL and still want a "PostBack" approach, my recommendation is still a different route. Instead use a `LinkButton` which would be a more "traditional" way (in ASP.NET Web Forms) to do a PostBack and pass data:

So instead, have markup like:

```
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="_room104" OnCommand="RoomCommand" CommandArgument="104" Text="Room 104" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton ID="_room105" OnCommand="RoomCommand" CommandArgument="105" Text="Room 105" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton></li>
```

and then code behind like:

```
protected void RoomCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int roomId = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse((string)e.CommandArgument, out roomId)) {
        //do something with roomId
    }
}
```

Comment: looks interesting but the link now doesn't have anything to go to the c# code? also if i want to get the id of the room in the page_load how it will return it?

Comment: @usertfwr I updated the answer with a more "traditional" way of accomplishing what you want to do. I think this would make more sense to other web forms programmers.

Comment: @usertfwr my initial post simply reads the `id` of the room on `Page_Load` in the `RoomClick` function because it is in the querystring (it got there from the `a` tag). It also safely casts it as an integer because that seems the appropriate data type. The "updated" post shows how to do it with a PostBack, while the initial answer showed how to do it with no postback since you are using the `URL`, not a server click event. Depends on what you are trying to do and how you want the user to interact with your page. I think either way is a more clear method than reading `href`.

Comment: @usertfwr in looking at another one of your questions, this problem seems to be a recurring issue for you. I'd recommend the `LinkButton` route and read up more on it [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).